# email box existence check and avoid blacklist

Tags: email-validation

There are so many articles stating the way we can check the email address existence which is nothing by sending smtp commands to the host.

The intention is cleaner to avoid sending out emails to addresses which do not exist.

Will the email service providers (GMail, Outlook) treat this as spam or may be skimming process and hence blacklist the IP address?
Is there any way it can be avoided from being blacklisted like this?

Answer (score 0):

SMTP protocols have a command [VRFY command](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-3.5) that is used to verify the existence of an email address.

For security reasons, this command is usually disabled.    Gmail, Hotmail, and many other email service providers (ESP) do not support VRFY.

So for many ESPs, the only way to test is to send an email.

Whether or not you trigger a blacklist depends on many factors, such as:
Email Volume
IP Repuation
Domain Reputation
Frequency of Testing

If you have an IP network that already sends high volumes of email to Gmail (100,000's), then testing a few thousand IPs will likely not cause issues. However, if you only send a few messages a day and then run a list of 1000 names, you would likely trigger their rate-based blacklist.

I suspect some email verification companies have unique relationships with the ESPs that help them avoid blacklists.  Others use networks of servers and 100's of IPs to run the test.

You do not know unless you try, but based on my work removing IPs from the Gmail blacklist, I suspect you would trigger blacklists if you had a large percentage of failed addresses, rapidly change email volume, or had other technical (DNS) errors.

For this reason, I would either use a service or use a different network and domain for testing.